# UninitializedPropertyAccessException occur when i use @inject in my presenter

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, retrofit, dagger-2

Am getting UninitializedPropertyAccessException when i inject a methord in my presenter

My provider class

```
@Module
class ActivityModule(private var activity: BaseActivity) {

@Provides
fun provideActivity(): BaseActivity {
    return activity
}


@Provides
@Inject
fun providePresenter(): MainContract.Presenter {
    return MainPresenter()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideGson(): Gson {

    return GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()
}

@Provides
@Inject
@Singleton
fun provideServiceGenerator(): ServiceGenerator {

    return ServiceGenerator()
 }
}
```

My component class

```
@Component(modules = [ActivityModule::class])
interface ActivityComponent {
fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
}
```

And in my Activity class i am injecting the Components as shown below

```
val activityComponent = DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
        .activityModule(ActivityModule(this))
        .build()
    activityComponent.inject(this)
```

All works fine in a button click i am calling one api As you can see in my provide i have **MainContract.Presenter**, am injecting the presenter in my activity and its injected successfully.

```
@Inject
lateinit var presenter: MainContract.Presenter
```

Now in My Presenter there is a **ServiceGenerator** class which i also provided in my provider class and i am injecting the service generatort in my presenter,The proble happens when i call the presenter the injected **ServiceGenerator** inside the presenter is giving UninitializedPropertyAccessException What is the cause of it and how can i solve this?
The snippet of presenter class as shown below

```
class MainPresenter : MainContract.Presenter {
@Inject
lateinit var serviceGenerator: ServiceGenerator
```

When i going for `val newsService = serviceGenerator.createService(ApiService::class.java,Constants.BASE_URL)`

call am getting the error,Please guide me if am doing anything wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of two things:

- Stick with property/field injection for your presenter, in this case you need to add an `inject` method for it in your Component, and call it in your presenter, just like you've done with your `Activity`.
- Use constructor injection, this way the presenter's dependencies will be injected "automatically" when it's injected in the `Activity`:

  ```
  class MainPresenter @Inject constructor(
      private val serviceGenerator: ServiceGenerator
  ) : MainContract.Presenter {

  }
  ```

Comment: first methord i dont understand can you give an example,also as per you 2 nd point i need to do  Provides
    Inject
    fun providePresenter(): MainContract.Presenter {
        return MainPresenter(ServiceGenerator(provideGson()))
    }, is that you mean?